# view images using HttpSelfHostServer

Tags: c#, self-hosting

I created a HttpSelfHostServer service hosting controller for communication in web API
problem is that I want the ability to view images
ex: *http://localhost:8080/images/pic.jpg*

but the self host doesn't allow me to do this
it use to be `IAppBuilder.UseFileServer` but it's different with HttpSelfHostServer

here's the server code

```
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Integration.WebApi;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.SelfHost;

namespace WebAPIServerV2
{
    public class WebAPIServer 
    {
        private HttpSelfHostServer m_Server;
        private ILifetimeScope m_lifetimeScope;

        public WebAPIServer(ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope)
        {
            m_lifetimeScope = lifetimeScope;
        }
        public void Start(string url)
        {
            if (m_Server != null)
            {
                Stop();
            }

            var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(url);
            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(m_lifetimeScope);
            config.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
            
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "ServerAPI",
               routeTemplate: "server/{controller}/{action}"

                );
            config.Formatters.Clear();
            config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings =
            new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
            };
            m_Server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
            m_Server.OpenAsync().Wait();
            if (Environment.UserInteractive)
                Console.WriteLine($"WebAPI server start at:{url}");
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            m_Server?.Dispose();
            m_Server = null;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well I found it!
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ed7e5248-69e2-4644-aa02-8da7d13c9765/hosting-a-file-with-httpselfhostserverhttpselfhostconfiguration?forum=aspwebapi

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPIServer
{
    internal class StaticFileHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.StartsWith("/server/"))
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            
            var path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            var newUri = new Uri(path);
            var newPath = newUri.AbsolutePath + request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath;
            newUri = new Uri(newPath);
            if (!File.Exists(newUri.LocalPath))
            {
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
            else
            {
                return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    var response = request.CreateResponse();
                    response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(newUri.LocalPath, FileMode.Open));
                    return response;
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ofcourse `server` is the prefix for the API so it was easy